# the username and request.user name has the same value but django python doesnt' recognise it as the same

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

why am i getting not the same user

Here is what in my views.py

```
def upost(request, username):
if request.method == 'GET':
    vng_u = request.user
    us = username
    vd_u  = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    p_o_u = Name.objects.filter(user=vd_u).order_by('id').reverse()
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        if (vng_u == us):
            s = "same"
        else:
            s = "not"

        pgntr = Paginator(p_o_u,1)
        pn = request.GET.get('page')
        pgobj = pgntr.get_page(pn)
        return render(request, "network/users.html", {
            "xp": p_o_u,
            "pc": pgobj,
            "postuser": us,
            "uv":   vng_u,
            "s":s
        })
```

here is what in my html

```
 {% if uv == postuser %}
```

same
{%else%}
not the same
{% endif %}

{{s}}

```
<div id="post-users"><br>
    Viewer:    <strong id="v1">{{uv}}</strong><br>
    Poster:    <strong id="v2">{{postuser}}</strong>
    {% for x in xp %}<br><hr>
        Content:    {{x.content}}<br>
                    {{x.timestamp}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and here is what appears on the html web page[image: it reads not the same]

Comment: I'd recommend naming your variables a little more verbosely. `xp`, `vng`, `uv` `p_o_u` are pretty hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `User` with the name `foo` is not the same as a string `'foo'`. This thus means that `vng_u == us` will always be `False`.

You can check if the user names match with:

```
if vng_u.username == us:
    # …
    pass
```

or you can retrieve the user with the given username, and then check if it is equal to `vng_u`:

```
vd_u = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
if vng_u == vd_u:
    …
    pass
```

Comment: thank you very much i've been figuring this out for a week now, i really got tired of figuring this out, THANK YOU